# How keep previous draw on same canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am able to draw a text on canvas on motion view now the problem is that when i draw text & go for the next draw on same canvas my draw text is getting disappear i mean screen is getting redraw because of invalidate i want keep my previous draw and make new draw on same canvas how am i going to do that ?

```
public class PuzzleView extends View {

private float width; // width of one tile
private float height; // height of one tile
private int selX; // X index of selection
private int selY; // Y index of selection
private final Rect selRect = new Rect();
private final Game game;
float positionX = 5;
float positionY = 15;
String strgettile = null;
float x, y;
Paint foreground = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
String getorientation;

public PuzzleView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.game = (Game) context;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    width = w / 9f;
    height = h / 9f;
    // getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSizeChanged: width " + width + ", height " + height);
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    // canvas.save();
    // Draw the background...
    Paint background = new Paint();
    background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_background));
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);

    // Draw the board...
    // Define colors for the grid lines
    Paint dark = new Paint();
    dark.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_dark));

    Paint hilite = new Paint();
    hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hilite));

    Paint light = new Paint();
    light.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_light));

    // Draw the minor grid lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, light);
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1,
                hilite);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), light);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(),
                hilite);
    }

    // Draw the major grid lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 != 0)
            continue;
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, dark);
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1,
                hilite);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), dark);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(),
                hilite);
    }
    // // Draw the numbers...


    Paint hint = new Paint();

    int m;
    if (strgettile != null) {
        for (m = 0; m < strgettile.length(); m++) {
            System.out.println(strgettile.charAt(m));

            char convertst = strgettile.charAt(m);
            String characterToString = Character.toString(convertst);

            if (getorientation.equalsIgnoreCase("Horizontal")) {
                canvas.drawText(characterToString, m * width + positionX,
                        positionY, foreground); // for motion event
                hint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                hint.setTextSize(45);


            } else {
                canvas.drawText(characterToString, positionX, m * height
                        + positionY, foreground);
                hint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                hint.setTextSize(45);

            }

        }
        //invalidate();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    // select((int) (event.getX() / width), (int) (event.getY() /
    // height));
    game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
    foreground.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_foreground));
    foreground.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    foreground.setTextSize(height * 0.75f);
    foreground.setTextScaleX(width / height);
    foreground.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    // // Draw the number in the center of the tile
    FontMetrics fm = foreground.getFontMetrics();
    // // Centering in X: use alignment (and X at midpoint)

    // positionX = width / 2;
    // // Centering in Y: measure ascent/descent first
    // positionY = height / 2 - (fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2;
    positionX = (int) event.getX();
    positionY = (int) event.getY() - (fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2;

    // Draw the numbers...
    // Define color and style for numbers

    // invalidate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: x " + selX + ", y " + selY);
    return true;
}

public void setSelectedTile(String tile, String strorientations) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("getting string in puzzle view ", tile);
    strgettile = tile;
    getorientation = strorientations;
    invalidate();
   }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Call `invalidate()` at the end of onDraw.
This function let the onDraw to get called again.

Comment: where should i keep that invalidate() setSelectedTile method is used that shall i remove this method from there?

Comment: @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  

  
   invalidate();
  }
  
 } shall i used like this

Comment: I can't find the method you are talking about, anyway put the invalidate at the very on end of OnDraw after you drawn everything and eventually updated your variables. This will create a loop of onDraw calls

Comment: And when are you using this method? My suggestion is to put the invalidate only after the if next to the creation of your paint.

Comment: ok i will do that actually i am getting values from dialog box at that time i m using this method

Comment: Ok you can still use it to update your instance variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65588/discussion-between-kirti-and-cloud57).